# yii2 запрос INNER JOIN c массивом значений

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

Есть таблица с квартирами и у каждой квартиры есть удобства. Удобства разные и разное количество их. Мне надо выбрать только те квартиры в которых есть определенный список удобств. Т.е. мне нужно чтобы показались квартиры у которых есть и утюг и стиралка.

```
 $query->innerJoinWith(['equipmentsToApartments' => function ($q) {
        $q->andWhere(['IN',  'equipment_id' ,[2, 10]]);
        return $q;
    }]);
```

такой код работает. Но получается, выбираются квартиры у которых есть или 2, или 10, или 2,10. А мне надо чтобы только 2,10.
'IN' тут получается как OR, а надо AND.

Comment: Тогда надо дополнительно группировать по квартире и проверять, что `COUNT(DISTINCT equipment_id)` равен двум.

Comment: а как это всё написать то?

Comment: Я могу только дать решение на raw SQL.

Comment: хотя бы так. хоть какая то инфа )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможные подходы на "чистом" SQL:

- при строго 2 параметрах

  ```
  SELECT [DISTINCT] t1.id
  FROM sourcetable t1
  JOIN sourcetable t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
  WHERE t1.field = @value1
    AND t2.field = @value2
  ```
- при неопределённом количестве параметров

  ```
  SELECT id
  FROM sourcetable
  WHERE field IN (@value1, @value2, ...)
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT([DISTINCT] @value) = @count_of_values
  ```

Comment: спасибо так всё заработало